# Monaca/Cordova バーコードプラグイン使用時、画面が横向きになってしまう

Tags: monaca

どうもおせわになります。
Monaca/Cordova バーコードプラグインを使ってAndroidタブレット向けのアプリケーションの開発をしています。
バーコード読み取り画面が必ず横向きとなりますが、縦向きにすることは可能でしょうか？
入力画面が縦向きでの使用を想定しているため、バーコード読取の場合もできれば縦向きにしたいです。
ご存知の方、教えていただけたら助かります。

Answer (score 1):

2015年12月、AsialのMonacaサポート担当に同様の件で質問しました。
返答は、現在横強制のため縦はできないとの事でした。
今後対応するかもとの事ですが、あまり期待しない方が良さそうです。

他に何か方法ないか聞いた所、cordovaあたりで自分でプラグイン作成すれば、
Monacaでやれない事もないそうです。。。w

クライアントを説得できないなら、cordovaやるより早めにネイティブに切り替えるのも手だと思いますよ。

Answer (score 0):

Android
「設定」->「Android設定」の画面下方にあります

iOS
「設定」->「iOS設定」の画面下方にあります。

Answer (score 0):

使っているプラグインはこちらでしょうか？
https://github.com/monaca-plugins/mobi.monaca.plugins.BarcodeScanner
plugin.xmlを確認すると
plugin > platform > config-file > activityタグに

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

という値が設定されています。
これを

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

に変更すればよいかもしれません。

別リポジトリですが変更されているものもあるようです。
https://github.com/Dbuggerx/BarcodeScanner

（見当違いな回答でしたら失礼しました…）

Comment: cowta様、user13314様 ご回答、どうもありがとうございます。 使っているのは、下記のプラグインです。 ⇒https://github.com/monaca-plugins/mobi.monaca.plugins.BarcodeScanner プラグインの設定をandroid:screenOrientation="portrait"に更新してインポートして確認しました。 画面は、縦向きに変わりました。 ただ、画面が丸ごと左90度に変わったようなイメージとなり、カメラの枠の位置が変になって バーコードと合わせるのは難しくなってしまいました。 他にももう少し修正が必要のようです。 下記のプラグインも試しましたが、スキャン画面が立ち上がりませんでした。 ⇒https://github.com/Dbuggerx/BarcodeScanner また、よろしくお願いします。